# Blurry image when using LiipImagineBundle Symfony 3

Tags: php, image, symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I've read the documentation to install and use LiipImagineBundle in Symfony 3 and when I want to resize an image that was uploaded through my administration interface, it becomes blurry. If an editor publishes a very large picture I would like it to be resized automatically to be displayed on my site. I do not understand why my image gets very blurry and does not resize to the specified size..

config.yml :

```
liip_imagine:
filter_sets:

    # name our filter set "my_thumb_filter"
    my_thumb_filter:
        filters:

            # use and setup the "thumbnail" filter
            thumbnail:

                # set the thumbnail size to "500x500" pixels
                size: [500, 500]

                # crop the input image, if required
                mode: outbound
```

Twig :

```
<img src="{{ ('bundles/sg/images/articles/' ~ article.image2.file ~ '.' ~ article.image2.extension) | imagine_filter('my_thumb_filter') }}" alt="{{ article.titre }}">
```

I created a media/cache folder and my image is placed correctly in the "articles" folder (http://localhost/SG/web/media/cache/my_thumb_filter/bundles/sg/images/articles/c71068976ec6efefc3c3c75886c6089b.jpeg)

Thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: Is the the `web_profiler` set to [not intercept redirects](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html#create-thumbnails)? `web_profiler:{ intercept_redirects: false }`

Comment: [thumbnail mode](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters/sizing.html#thumbnail-options) `outbound` crops images when they are larger than the specified dimensions, where `inset` resizes them. If you want smaller images to be enlarged you would need to set `allow_upscale: true`